# Firemonkey: How to draw just a point on a canvas

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I m just a little surprised but It looks like on firemonkey there is no easy way to draw a single point on a Canvas? or I m tired and I miss something?

As many ask me, below a sample of what I want to achieve (I want to also make a dynamique animation and move each dots on the fly)

[image]

Comment: You could simply draw/fill a 1x1 rectangle at the desired coordinate. Or, perhaps, use `TCanvas.Bitmap` to access the raw pixel data and set the desired pixel directly.

Comment: yes i know but it's will be a quite inefficient way :(

Comment: @loki: Inefficient compared to what? The VCL `TCanvas.Pixels` property is *really* slow. Also, today you probably shouldn't draw a single pixel anyway, because different users have vastly different resolutions (pixels per inch). On a high-res display, a single pixel isn't even visible!

Comment: @loki did you actually profile that, or are you just speculating?

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand `TCanvas` does not have a `Pixels` property in FMX, but it does have a `Bitmap` property, and `TBitmap` in FMX has a `Map()` method for direct pixel access (FMX's equivalent to `TBitmap.ScanLine` in VCL)

Comment: @RemyLebeau: I suspected that. But you can still make *comparisons* against the VCL property, which is really slow (so you need to use scanlines instead).

Comment: @RemyLebeau no i didn't profile, but OpenGL have GL_POINTS primitive, it's a little sad to use only GL_TRIANGLES / GL_lines :( Using bitmap to access the pixel will be the worse because you will need to copy to data from the GPU to the CPU, access the pixels and then back move the data to the GPU :( In fact I was just curious to notice that their is not a trivial function drawPoint

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand I mean ineficient regarding using the GL_POINTS primitive offered by openGL

Comment: Could you explain why you have to draw a single pixel? I bet you have a lot of pixel to write. Once we know what's your final goal, we can - maybe - give some advice about how to achieve that goal. If you have a lot of pixel to write, maybe you should build your image off screen in a bitmap and then blast the bitmap on screen.

Comment: @fpiette right now i don't need, but was just curious why their was no drawPoint :(

Comment: @loki If you're ever curious why something you don't need doesn't exist, just wait around to see if you ever need it.  If you never do, that's probably a good reason why it doesn't exist.

Comment: @J... Ok, so I just edited the question, and show exactly why i want to achieve (with animation)

Comment: You are reinventing the square wheel.  What you are trying to achieve is called a graph or a chart.  You don't need to draw them one pixel at a time.  A TChart would be a place to start.

Comment: If you're really determined, and if by "point" you mean a chart marker and not a single pixel, then a way to draw a circle or ellipse on a chart is to use the [Ellipse](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/Vcl.Graphics.TCanvas.Ellipse) method.

Comment: @j.. yes i know Tchart, but i want to do some animation, i just need to draw point on a canvas. their is thousands scenario where we need it. you have opengl primitive for it (with point size even to say the size of the point). of course i can draw a circle to represent my point, but stay honest, this will be inefficient regarding using the point primitive (especially if i want to make animation)

Comment: TChart supports animations, at least in the pro sku.  If you want to draw on a canvas, what's wrong with the [Ellipse](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/Vcl.Graphics.TCanvas.Ellipse) method?

Comment: @j... their is no Ellipse method in openGL. only line, point and triangle. I m not sure how the delphi code will translate a circle of 1 pixel to openGL, in 1 or many triangles? i don't know need to try. but what i m certain is that drawpoint will be much more efficient

Comment: Your question is asking about drawing on a canvas.  I don't see where OpenGL enters into it.

Comment: @J... because I m on firemonkey, so at the end it's openGL (or directX under windows, but in fact it's the same, directX also have only point, line and triangle primitive). Canvas is just a way to discuss with openGL

Comment: Ok, so [DrawEllipse](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/FMX.Graphics.TCanvas.DrawEllipse), then.  Are you trying to draw a single pixel, or are you trying to draw a *point* on a graph (like the blue dots in the image you've shown)?

Comment: @J... right now a single pixel :( the picture was just a sample. but in fact with opengl you have the pointsize so doesn't really matter if the point is one or several pixels

Comment: @j... :( you are right just I didn't have any other sample now. originally I just want to confirm that their is no way to paint a single pixel on the canvas (easily i mean) and this why all of you just confirm me

Comment: There is a way - Remy mentioned it above.  Use the [Map](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/FMX.Graphics.TBitmap.Map) property of the `TCanvas.Bitmap` and you can set pixel values manually.

Comment: @J... map is the worse think to do :( it's will copy the texture bits from the GPU to the memory, then you update manually the pixel you want to update and then inject back ALL the bits to the GPU :( all of this everytime just to update one pixel :(

Comment: You asked how to draw one pixel. We told you but you don't like it. You should have asked "How to draw one pixel without using MAP:.